# Setting a minimum width in listings

Tags: listings

I'm trying to create a few listings of some code files with varying max line-length. Is there a way to ensure that all listings have a 63-character width, regardless of how long its longest line is? I tried to use the `linewidth` option but it didn't appear to work, plus I had to give it a length rather than the amount of characters I'd like for the line to be as long as.

Is there an option as simple as `setminimumwidth=63`? I tried the documentation but `linewidth` was all I could find.

Edit: This is a modified code off Zxcvasdf's answer, meant for `standalone`-class documents. It works as intended for lines below 64 chars, but `standalone`'s cropping adds extra space to the right when the lines are longer than 63.

```
\documentclass[10pt,tikz,
margin={6mm 0 0 2mm} % left bottom right up
]{standalone}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    frame=tb,
    basewidth=4.5pt, % half of small font size
    breaklines,
    linewidth=283.5pt, % number of cols * basewidth = 63 * 4.5 pt
    numbers = left
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% hack: ensure the listing is 63-chars long
\draw (283.5pt,0) circle [radius=0mm];

\node at (0,0) {
\begin{lstlisting}
some
code
\end{lstlisting}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output looks as intended for 63-or-less char lines
[image: Output looks as intended for 63-or-less char lines]

Original MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,dvipsnames,margin={0.8cm 0 0 0}]{standalone}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  linewidth=20em} % How to set a minimum char-based width?

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node at (0,0) {
    \begin{lstlisting}
    some
    code
    \end{lstlisting}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your document font size. If you use a 10pt normal font, then `\small` uses 9pt. Together with `basewidth` option, you can set the character limit.

In the following listing, the letter `l` in the phrase `l ong` ends at 63rd column, and as desired, the code linebreaks here.

```tex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tikz}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    frame=tb,
    basewidth=4.5pt, % half of small font size
    breaklines,
    linewidth=283.5pt, % number of cols * basewidth = 63 * 4.5 pt
} % How to set a minimum char-based width?

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    
\node at (0,0) {
\begin{lstlisting}
some
code
A long long long long long long long long long long long long l ong long line
\end{lstlisting}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**

It turns out if you remove the `tikzpicture` environment, then the `varwidth` option of `standalone` takes care of things.

```tex
\documentclass[varwidth,border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    frame=tb,
    basewidth=4.5pt, % half of small font size
    breaklines,
    postbreak={\space\space\space},
    linewidth=283.5pt, % number of cols * basewidth = 63 * 4.5 pt
} % How to set a minimum char-based width?

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
some
code
A long long long long long long long long long long long long l ong long line
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit 2**

If you want shorter codes to retain the same length, this is another hack that doesn't use tikz.

```tex
\documentclass[varwidth,border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    frame=tb,
    basewidth=4.5pt, % half of small font size
    breaklines,
    postbreak={\space\space\space},
    linewidth=283.5pt, % number of cols * basewidth = 63 * 4.5 pt
} % How to set a minimum char-based width?

\begin{document}
\rule{283.5pt}{0pt}
\begin{lstlisting}
some
code
A long long long long long long long long long long long long l ong long line
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Output for short code:
[image]

Output for long code:
[image]

As you may notice, the 0pt rule introduces some vertical spacing above the listing, I wasn't able to get rid of that.

Comment: I like this answer! I tweaked this code a bit and it worked just great for `standalone`s. I'll accept it in a bit unless someone finds a way to fix the `standalone` spacing issues for longer lines